# Rowmotion of matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, matroid-theory

If $Z$ is a finite poset, then we say that a collection $\mathcal{A}$ is an antichain if whenever $y,z\in\mathcal{A}$, if $y\leq z$, then $y=z$. If $R\subseteq Z$, then let $L(R)$ be the set of all $x\in Z$ where there is some $y\in R$ with $x\leq y$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an antichain, then let $\mathcal{A}^+$ be the collection of all minimal elements in $Z\setminus L(\mathcal{A})$. The mapping $\mathcal{A}\mapsto\mathcal{A}^{+}$ is a bijection from the collection of all anti-chains in $Z$ to the collection of all anti-chains in $Z$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an anti-chain, then define an anti-chain $\mathcal{A}^{[n]}$ for all integers $n$ by setting $\mathcal{A}^{[0]}=\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}^{[n+1]}=(\mathcal{A}^{[n]})^{+}$. Sam Hopkins reminded us that this operation $\mathcal{A}\mapsto\mathcal{A}^{+}$ is called rowmotion.

If $X$ is a finite set, then we say that a non-empty subset $\mathcal{A}\subseteq P(X)$ is a matroid (for this post, we are using the basis definition of a matroid) if whenever $R,S\in\mathcal{A},R\neq S$ and $r\in R\setminus S$, there is some $s\in S\setminus R$ where $(R\setminus\{r\})\cup\{s\}\in\mathcal{A}$.

For this post, if $n$ is an integer, then we say that an anti-chain $\mathcal{A}$ is an $n$-matroid if $\mathcal{A}^{[-n]}$ is a matroid.

The 0-matroids are just the matroids, and the 1-matroids are the antichains $\mathcal{A}\subseteq P(X)$ such that $\emptyset\not\in\mathcal{A}$ and if $R,S\in\mathcal{A}$, and $t\in R\cap S$, then there is some $T\in\mathcal{A}$ with $T\subseteq(R\cap S)\setminus\{t\}$ (this is just the circuit definition of a matroid).

As mentioned by Sam Hopkins in the comments, the $-1$-matroids are the hyperplane matroids. An hyperplane matroid is an antichain $\mathcal{A}\subseteq P(X)$ such that if $x\in X,R,S\in\mathcal{A},x\not\in R\cup S$, then there is some $T\in\mathcal{A}$ with $(R\cap S)\cup\{x\}\subseteq T$.

If $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$, then is there a reasonable way to define the notion of an $n$-matroid that does not explicitly refer to the cycling operation $\mathcal{A}\mapsto\mathcal{A}^+$? If the case for general $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ just gets more and more complex as $n$ gets further away from $0$, then I would be interested even in how one may characterize the $2$-matroids or the $-2$-matroids.

Example: If $Z$ is a finite set with $|Z|=r$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of all $k$-element subsets of $Z$, then $\mathcal{A}^{[n]}$ is the collection of all subsets $R\subseteq X$ with $k+n \mod r+2$ many elements. In particular, $Z$ is an $n$-matroid for all integers $n$.

Comment: The operation on antichains you describe is now often called "rowmotion"; see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1172 and papers citing it. However, regarding matroids specifically, you might be interested in the early paper "Loops of clutters" by Deza and Fukuda https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-8994-1_7.

Comment: In particular, according to that paper the $-1$-matroids are the sets of hyperplanes of matroids.

Comment: If we define the rowmotion order of a matroid $\mathcal{A}$ over a set $X$ to be the least $n>0$ where $\mathcal{A}^{[n]}=\mathcal{A}$, then for the linear matroids that I have tested, the rowmotion order of $\mathcal{A}$ tends to be equal to $|X|+2$ or either a factor or multiple of $|X|+2$.

Comment: In general if $P$ is a graded poset of rank $n$, then $n+2$ is the "expected" order of rowmotion because $P_{\leq -1}, P_{\leq 0}, P_{\leq 1}, \ldots, P_{\leq n}$ is a rowmotion orbit, where $P_{\leq i}$ is the subposet of elements of rank $\leq i$. But except for very special posets like the product of two chains, there will be "bad" orbits with size much bigger than $n+2$. In particular for the Boolean lattice the behavior of rowmotion is chaotic. Although I'm not sure the effect restricting to antichains corresponding to matroids has.